# Python regular expression issue

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use the re module in a way that it will return bunch of characters until a particular string follows an individual character. The re documentation seems to indicate that I can use (?!...) to accomplish this. The example that I'm currently wrestling with:

```
str_to_search = 'abababsonab, etc'
first = re.search(r'(ab)+(?!son)', str_to_search)
second = re.search(r'.+(?!son)', str_to_search)
```

first.group() is 'abab', which is what I'm aiming for. However, second.group() returns the entire str_to_search string, despite the fact that I'm trying to make it stop at 'ababa', as the subsequent 'b' is immediately followed by 'son'. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to INCLUDE the full `ababab` prior to `son` or just the first `abab` stopping before `abson`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
second = re.search(r'(.(?!son))+', str_to_search)
#output: 'ababa'
```

Comment: Not sure why you used .? and not .

Comment: This worked (and was the easiest for me to wrap my brain around). Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: What @void has is a repeated capture group, which appears as match group 1, and overwrites itself each iteration of the +.  That's why I added the ?: ... Just a warning to anyone who tries to understand what's going on exactly with this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the simplest thing, but you can capture a repeating sequence of "a character not followed by 'son'".  This repeated expression should be in a non-capturing group, (?: ... ), so it doesn't mess with your match results. (You'd end up with an extra match group)

Try this:

```
import re

str_to_search = 'abababsonab, etc'
second = re.search(r'(?:.(?!son))+', str_to_search)
print(second.group())
```

Output:

```
ababa
```

See it here: http://ideone.com/6DhLgN

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do

1. check out string.partition
2. '.+?' is the minimal matcher, otherwise it is greedy and gets it all
3. read the docs for group(...) and groups(..) especially when passing group number